# Are there accounts detailing personal encounters with the Rambam and referring to his personality?

Tags: history, rambam

The Rambam, at least in his writing, is often forthright, reassured and direct. It seems to me that sometimes the Rambam can be construed as disparaging of certain groups of people. For example (introduction to perek helek):

> You must know that the words of the sages are differently interpreted by three groups of people. The first group...  They hold such opinions because they have not understood science and are far from having acquired knowledge. They possess no perfection which would rouse them to insight from within, nor have they found anyone else to stimulate them to profounder understanding. They, therefore, believe that the sages intended no more in their carefully emphatic and straightforward utterances than they themselves are able to understand with inadequate knowledge. They understand
> the teachings of the sages only in their literal sense, in spite of the fact that some of their teachings when taken literally, seem so fantastic and irrational that if one were to repeat them literally, even to the uneducated, let alone sophisticated scholars, their amazement would prompt them to ask how anyone in the world could believe such things true, much less edifying. The members of this group are poor in knowledge. **One can only regret their folly. Their very effort to honor and to exalt the sage sin accordance with their own meager understanding actually humiliates them. As God lives, this group destroys the glory of the Torah of God say the opposite of what it intended.**

and also...

> The second group... They regard themselves as cultivated men, scientist, critics, and philosophers. How remote they are from true humanity compared to real philosophers! **They are more stupid than the first group; many of them are simply fools.** **This is an accursed group**, because they attempt to refute men of established greatness whose wisdom has been demonstrated to competent men of science. If these fools had worked at science hard enough to know how to write
> accurately about theology and similar subjects both for the masses and for the educated, and if they understood the relevance of philosophy, then they would be in a position to understand whether the sages were in fact wise or not, and the real meaning of their teachings would be clear to them.

The "third group", says the Rambam is "so few in number that it is hardly appropriate to call them a group" (i.e., one that properly understand chazal and their greatness/intelligence which points to profound truths). It seems like the Rambam considers this third group the one to which we should strive to belong. It seems like the Rambam is saying that almost everyone has 'got it all wrong'.

There are also instances in The Guide where he sets out a case for the primacy of the intellect in getting closer to God, suggesting that those who cannot reach intellectual heights are considerably handicapped when it comes to closeness to God. Or that those who read the Torah literally are fools.

Leaving aside the philosophy of the Rambam in this regard, I am looking for accounts of those who met the Rambam and described what he was like. In view of his (sometimes) rather disparaging views in writing, I wonder what he was like as a person and whether this kind of language came across to those who met him.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/36974874/Paul_B._Fenton_A_Meeting_with_Maimonides_Bulletin_of_the_School_of_Oriental_and_African_Studies_45_1_1982_1-4